# Highchart on mobile (Touch to zoom out and zoom in) - LineChart

Tags: javascript, mobile, highcharts, zooming

I'm trying to apply ZoomIn and ZoomOut in a line chart on a mobile device. The goal is to click on a zone of the chart and ZoomIn in the first click and ZoomOut on the second. The sequence will always be this one.

I already live to see the documentation / examples and I can not find anything to solve this situation.

I have already tried using this properties in the `chart:` property

```
pinchType : 'y',
zoomType: 'none'
```

I tried the `zoomtype` but the behavior is not what I expect. I want to have a click to zoom this specific area of ​​the chart. I do not want to zoom with two fingers.

```
{
    chart: {
        pinchType : 'x'
    },
    legend: {
        itemStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'spline',
            color : '#fff'
        },
        {
            dashStyle: 'longdash',
            color: '#b3be77'
        }
    ],
}
```

As simple as clicking to get zoomin and zoomout

Comment: I wanted something like this. But one click make zoomIn and another ZoomOut. http://highchartsweb.vifi.ee/maps/demo/doubleclickzoomto/grid-light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the second challenge can be easily achieved by adding this logic to `plotOptions.series.events.click` callback function:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.clickedOnce = false;
      },
      click: function() {
        const chart = this;

        if (chart.clickedOnce) {
            chart.zoomOut();
          chart.clickedOnce = false;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          const chart = this.chart,
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];

          let x,
            y,
            rangeX,
            rangeY;

          if (!chart.clickedOnce) {
            x = xAxis.toValue(e.chartX);
            y = yAxis.toValue(e.chartY);
            rangeX = xAxis.max - xAxis.min;
            rangeY = yAxis.max - yAxis.min;

            xAxis.setExtremes(x - rangeX / 10, x + rangeX / 10, false);
            yAxis.setExtremes(y - rangeY / 10, y + rangeY / 10, false);
            chart.redraw();

            chart.clickedOnce = true;
          } else {
            chart.zoomOut();
            chart.clickedOnce = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demos:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kotgea5n/
- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s8w2xg3e/1/

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not implemented in Highcharts by default, but you can easily achieve it by adding your custom logic when the chart area is clicked.

When area is clicked the first time use `axis.setExtremes()` method to zoom in. On the second click use `chart.zoomOut()` to zoom out the chart. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.clickedOnce = false;
      },
      click: function(e) {
        const chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];

        let x,
          y,
          rangeX,
          rangeY;

        if (!chart.clickedOnce) {
          x = xAxis.toValue(e.chartX);
          y = yAxis.toValue(e.chartY);
          rangeX = xAxis.max - xAxis.min;
          rangeY = yAxis.max - yAxis.min;

          xAxis.setExtremes(x - rangeX / 10, x + rangeX / 10, false);
          yAxis.setExtremes(y - rangeY / 10, y + rangeY / 10, false);
          chart.redraw();

          chart.clickedOnce = true;
        } else {
          chart.zoomOut();
          chart.clickedOnce = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fxm812k4/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#zoomOut
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click

---

Using a `customEvents` plugin (see: https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events) and adding plotBand on the whole chart area you can register a callback on click and double click events. Using this approach you can make a zoom in on click event and zoom out on double click (not working on mobile devices).

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6tpb5q2z/

Comment: New challenge :).

Zoom is set for the whole map, but the goal is to zoomIn on a Series value. Zooming should only happen when the user clicks on a point on the map. Should not zoom when the user does not click in the points.  Is it possible to add this event to each value in the series? Using the "this." as the element of the chart clicked? I try but don't work.

Comment: Something like this but to zoom - https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-click/

Comment: Hello Wojciech. Can you help me in the doubleclick event problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What do you mean saying "doubleclick event problem"?

Comment: Here I have one-click function I want to change the event(function) to only work with double click on the screen. I want to do nothing in one click. Regards and many thanks